# devise token auth doesn't return access-token with React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I am moving an application from using devise to devise token auth.  I have added the gem, set up everything, etc.  My issue lies in the fact that when I make a request from React (using axios) to the backend it returns the user (as it should), but doesn't return the access-token headers.  All, I get is:

cache-control: "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
content-type:"application/json; charset=utf-8"

I do get the user object from the backend though so I know it is a valid sign in.  I also see tokens being added to the database:

UPDATE users SET tokens = '

Here is my call via axios:

```
export const userLogin = (options) => ((dispatch) => {
  return axios.post(`${process.env.DOMAIN}/auth/sign_in`, {email: 
    options.username, password: options.password})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("response is: ", response);
    dispatch(setUser(response))
    dispatch(loginError('', false))
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    dispatch(loginError('Username or Password is incorrect, please try again', 
  true))
  })
})
```

I have done quite a bit of research on this and tried reverting to an older version of active_model_serializers for example and this hasn't helped.  The console.log above shows quite a bit of info:
config
data
headers
request
status
statusText

The response is a 200 OK.